# My friend named..../ I have a friend named/called

Tags: grammaticality

Is it okay if I just say "My friend named"? or should I complete the sentence to "I have a friend named". Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: How about simply referring to "My friend James"?

Comment: - James is a really popular name.  - My friend named that. (is it correct?)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "My friend named James," though it sounds a tad stilted.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole bunch of choices here.

(normal, everyday): My friend James says he loves verismo opera. He's a known liaer.

(slightly pedantic): My friend, whose name is James, says he adores verismo opera. That's probably a lie.

(deliberately chummy): My friend, [by the] name of James, says he can't live without verismo opera. He's a lying, conniving jerk.

(overly formal): My friend, named James, says he knows how to appreciate verismo opera. I'm sure he's lying.

Comment: - James is a really popular name. - My friend named that. (is it correct?)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean _James is a popular name. I have a friend with that name_?

Comment: sorry about the ambiguity.. actually I meant that suppose that this is a dialogue starting with the one says "James is a really popular name." and then the other one answers "My friend named that"  I was asking if it is possible to answer like that.

Comment: @Alex: In that case, Kate's answer is perfect: "I have a friend with that name."